# Websphere commerce cookies not generated

Tags: websphere-commerce

We observed that in production site which had been newly set up, Websphere commerce is not generating the out of the box cookies like WC_ACTIVITY, WC_USERID, WC_PERSISTENCE etc. In fact, none of the commerce cookies are getting created except JSESSIONID.

I have been struggling with it for more than 2 days and couldn't find a solution. Can someone give some pointers on the same?

Note: I have compared the wc-server.xml from pre-prod and sit environments and it is exactly the same except the db and MQ connection details

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed. The problem was due to incorrect web.xml configuration